# Describing a one-point compactification

Tags: general-topology, compactness

*Show that $X = S^{1} \cup ((0,2) \times \{0\}) \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is locally compact and find its one-point compactification.*

**Definitions**

$S^{1}$ is the open unit circle. Our definitions are these -

A space $X$ is compact if a finite subcover can be extracted from every open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$. A space $X$ is locally compact if every element $x \in X$ admits a compact neighbourhood.

A one-point compactification of a topological space $(X, T)$ is a compact Hausdorff space $(\tilde{X}, \tilde{T})$ together with an embedding $i: X \rightarrow \tilde{X}$ with the property that $|\tilde{X} - X| = 1$.

**My questions**

Im not too sure about my proof of the local compactness of X:

Let $x \in X$, and let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of a subspace $A \subset X$ containing $x$. Then there exists an element $U \in \mathcal{U}$ so that $x \in U$. Choose $\delta_{U}$ so that $B(x, \delta_{U}) \subset U$. Then $B(x, \delta_{U})$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ and $U$ is its finite subcover.

In fact, reading it again, it feels wonky. Im still trying to develop an intuition for the notion of compactness. If it is indeed not correct, how would I start proving $X$ is locally compact?

Furthermore, I have no idea how to describe the one-point compactification of $X$. Ive made a drawing of $X$ and I think the final result should be homeomorphic to a figure resembling an 8, but how would I intuitively find this? And how would I then describe it rigorously?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: To show local compactness, show that each point of $X$ has a nbhd that is a closed, bounded subset of $\Bbb R^2$ and therefore is compact. (In fact every point of $X$ except $\langle 1,0\rangle$ has a nbhd homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.)

You are correct in thinking that $\tilde X$ is homeomorphic to a figure $8$; in effect the point at infinity turns the open segment $(0,2)\times\{0\}$ into a copy of $S^1$. Here’s a suggestion for a more rigorous writeup. First let

$$C=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:(x-2)^2+y^2=1\}\;,$$

the circle of radius $1$ centred at $\langle 2,0\rangle$, let $C_0=C\setminus\{\langle 3,0\rangle\}$, and let $Y=S^1\cup C_0$.

- Show that $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$; for instance, map $(0,1)\times\{0\}$ nicely to the open upper half of $C_0$ and $(1,2)\times\{0\}$ to the open lower half.
- Then show that $\tilde X$ is homeomorphic to $S^1\cup C$.

Comment: But if X is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ endowed with the Euclidian topology, isnt $T$ the induced subspace topology on $X$? Is it still possible to say a closed, bounded neighbourhood in $X$ is compact?

Im now diving into the second part.

Comment: If Im correct, I can just map $S^{1} \subset X$ to $S^{1} \subset Y$ and this "part" of the map should be continuous with regards to all possibilities for the topology chosen, and for $C_{0} \subset Y$ I could use 

$(x, 0) \mapsto (2+\cos(\pi x), \sin(\pi x))$ if $x \in (0, 1)$ and 

$(x, 0) \mapsto (2+\cos(\pi x), -\sin(\pi x))$ if $x \in (1, 2)$, right? 

The point $(1, 0)$ is technically there cause of the overlap with $S^{1}$, isnt it?

I still need to work this out a bit more, but Im hoping this is roughly the correct approach.

Comment: @Raylan: For your first question, a compact set is compact no matter what space it’s embedded in. Thus, since $X$ inherits its topology from $\Bbb R^2$, if a subset of $X$ is a closed, bounded set in $\Bbb R^2$, then it’s compact in $\Bbb R^2$ **and therefore in** $X$ **as well**. For your second question, I didn’t check the details of your mappings, but the idea is fine.

Comment: Would it then indeed follow that $\tilde{X}$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1} \cup C$ because if it were not, using the "trick" of removing a point so the result is still homeomorphic would lead to a contradiction?

Comment: @Raylan: I would argue differently: just show that the open nbhds of $\langle 3,0\rangle$ in $S^1\cup C$ are precisely the images of the open nbhds of the point at infinity in $\tilde X$.

Comment: Okay, I will try that! Before I forget, if possible Id like a bit more assistance with proving $X$ is locally compact. For instance, I dont know why $(1, 0)$ does not have a neighbourhood homeomorphic to $[0, 1]$. Can I not take $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}] \times \{0\} \subset X$ as a neighbourhood? And how would I prove $S^{1} \subset X$ is locally compact? I thought of mapping it to $[0, 2 \pi)$ but that leaves one point.

Comment: @Raylan: $S^1$ is a compact Hausdorff space, so it’s automatically locally compact. Nbhds of $\langle 1,0\rangle$ have to include not only horizontal intervals but also intervals up and down along the circle; it has a base of closed intervals homeomorphic to a $+$ sign.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Raylan: You’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I've read this answer and comments, but I am not sure why every neighborhood of $X$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. Can you explain it? Thanks!

Comment: @JBIBB: It’s not true that every nbhd of $X$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. What is true is that each point of $X$ except $\langle 1,0\rangle$ has a nbhd that is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. For instance, if $\langle x,0\rangle in X\setminus S^1$, set $\epsilon=\frac12|x-1|$; then $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]\times\{0\}$ is a nbhd of $\langle x,0\rangle$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. For a point $p$ on $S^1\setminus\{\langle 1,0\rangle\}$ do the essentially the same thing: take a closed arc of $S^1$ with $p$ at its centre that is short enough to miss $\langle 1,0\rangle$.